# Como agrupar elementos de un array del mismo tipo en un nuevo array php

Tags: php, array, foreach

Este es mi array php

```
$brands = array
(
    "Chevrolet" => "Spark",
    "Chevrolet" => "Aveo",
    "Ford" => "Fiesta",
    "Ford" => "Explorer",
    "Kia" => "Rio5",
    "Kia" => "Morning",
    "Suzuki" => "Alto",
    "Suzuki" => "Baleno"
);
```

yo quiero hacer un nuevo array donde se agrupen los modelos de autos en su marca respectiva y para ellos intento hacer esto:

```
public static function getcarbrand($brands)
    {
        $marge_cars_brand=array();
        foreach ($brands as $key => $value)
        {
            $marge_cars_brand[$key][]=$value;
        }
        return $marge_cars_brand;
    }
```

pero mi salida obtenida es esta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

entonces me dice que solo un modelo por marca de auto la idea es que muestre cada modelo por cada marca

Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: Partes de un `array()` en el que estás perdiendo datos. Al hacer `array('Chevrolet' => 'Spark', 'Chevrolet' => 'Aveo')` estás sobrescribiendo el índice **Chevrolet** machacando el valor **Spark** por **Aveo**. En los **array** asociativos el índice es único y actúa como si fuese el índice numérico de un array básico, por lo que realmente estás haciendo algo similar a esto: `$mi_array[0] = 1; $mi_array[0] = 2;` Deberías pensar en otra manera de almacenar los datos para evitar este problema.

Comment: Haz un `var_dump($brands);` y podrás comprobar lo que bien dice @phpMyGuel. Realmente tu array no tiene todos los elementos que crees que tiene, porque los índices repetidos se sobre-escriben. Deberías reconsiderar de qué forma estás constuyendo `$brands`, organizando una estructura adecuada, de modo que no tengas siquiera que seguir manipulando los datos una vez obtenidos.

Comment: @phpMyGuel gracias por tu respuesta ya entendi cual era mi problema

Comment: @A. Cedano gracias amigo